# How to implement an infix calculator with precedence and associativity

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm testing the example of writing an infix calculator using bison flex. I found that everything is right except for the brackets "()". I find that when I input a calculation with brackets, the calculation result is incorrect. Here is the code for file "infix-calc.y"

```
/* bison grammar file for infix notation calculator */
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex(void);


%}

%token NUM
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%left NEG
%right '^'

%% /* Grammer rules and actions follow */

input: /* empty */
     | input line
     ;

line: '\n'
    | exp '\n' { printf("\t%.10g\n", $1); }
    ;

exp: NUM { $$ = $1; }
   | exp '+' exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
   | exp '-' exp { $$ = $1 - $3; }
   | exp '*' exp { $$ = $1 * $3; }
   | exp '/' exp { $$ = $1 / $3; }
   | '-' exp %prec NEG { $$ = -$2; }
   | exp '^' exp { $$ = pow($1, $3); }
   | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
   ;

%%

/* Additional C code */

int main() { return yyparse(); }

int yyerror(const char* s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the code for file "infix-calc.lex"

```
/* lex file for infix notation calculator */
%option noyywrap

%{
#define YYSTYPE double     /* type for bison's var: yylval */
#include <stdlib.h>        /* for atof(const char*) */
#include "infix-calc.tab.h"
%}


digits [0-9]
rn     (0|[1-9]+{digits}*)\.?{digits}*
op     [+*^/\-]
ws     [ \t]+  


%%

{rn}   yylval = atof(yytext); return NUM;
{op}   |
\n     return *yytext;
{ws}   /* eats up white spaces */

%%
```

The problem is that when I input, say "2 * (3 + 4)", I'm supposed to receive the output "14". But the input is "()    10". It seems the brackets don't work in this case. What's wrong with the codes?
Thank you all very much for helping me!!!!

Comment: The yacc rules look OK. Maybe lex? Use printf statements in each rule to print which rule fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to declare `(` and `)` as tokens for this to work.

Add the following two lines before the final `%%` in your lex file:

```
"("    return LEFT;
")"    return RIGHT;
```

Then add

```
%token LEFT RIGHT
```

to the top of infix-calc.y, and replace

```
   | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
```

with

```
   | LEFT exp RIGHT { $$ = $2; }
```

Comment: It was only necessary to add the parentheses to the rule for single character tokens, although normal style would be to send a single-character token for any unrecognized input.